# Best way to generate code for writing out XML files

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a code generator to build classes based on XML data.  It makes (will make) updating the data straight forward.  For example, say I have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Records>
    <Band>Black Sabbath
        <Album>
            Paranoid
            <Date>1977</Date>
        </Album>
    </Band>
    <Band>Iron Maiden
        <Album>
            Killers
            <Date>1981</Date>
        </Album>
        <Album>
            PeiceOfMind
            <Date>1983</Date>
        </Album>
    </Band>
</Records>
```

It will create classes similar to these (I omitted the most of the functionality just to show the structure.

```
Public Class RecordsNode
    Inherits XmlClassBase


    Private _current As RecordsItem
    Private _errors As List(Of String)
    Private _orphans As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of XmlClassBase))


    Public Class BandNode
        Inherits XmlClassBase


        Private _current As BandItem
        Private _list As BandItem()


        Public Class AlbumNode
            Inherits XmlClassBase


            Private _current As AlbumItem
            Private _list As AlbumItem()


            Public Class DateNode
                Inherits XmlClassBase


                Private _current As DateItem
                Private _list As DateItem()



                Public Sub New()

                    _current = New DateItem(0)

                End Sub


                Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
                    Get
                        Return _current.Attributes
                    End Get
                End Property

                Public ReadOnly Property Current As DateItem
                    Get
                        Return _current
                    End Get
                End Property

                Public ReadOnly Property List As DateItem()
                    Get
                        Return _list
                    End Get
                End Property

                Public Overrides Property Text As String
                    Get
                        Return _current.Text
                    End Get
                    Set(value As String)
                        _current.Text = value
                    End Set
                End Property


                Public Overrides Sub Add()

                    If _list IsNot Nothing Then
                        ReDim Preserve _list(_list.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
                    Else
                        ReDim _list(0)
                    End If


                    _current = New DateItem(_list.GetUpperBound(0))
                    _list(_list.GetUpperBound(0)) = _current

                End Sub


                Public Function HasChildren() As Boolean

                    Return False

                End Function

            End Class

            Public Class DateItem

                Private _attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
                Private _deleted As Boolean
                Private _index As Integer
                Private _text As String


                Public Sub New(Index As Integer)

                    _index = Index
                End Sub

                Public ReadOnly Property Attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
                    Get
                        If _attributes Is Nothing Then
                            _attributes = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
                        End If
                        Return _attributes
                    End Get
                End Property

                Public ReadOnly Property ListIndex As Integer
                    Get
                        Return _index
                    End Get
                End Property

                Public Property Text As String
                    Get
                        Return _text
                    End Get
                    Set(value As String)
                        _text = value
                    End Set
                End Property

            End Class



            Public Sub New()

                _current = New AlbumItem(0)

            End Sub


            Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
                Get
                    Return _current.Attributes
                End Get
            End Property

            Public ReadOnly Property Current As AlbumItem
                Get
                    Return _current
                End Get
            End Property

            Public ReadOnly Property List As AlbumItem()
                Get
                    Return _list
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Overrides Property Text As String
                Get
                    Return _current.Text
                End Get
                Set(value As String)
                    _current.Text = value
                End Set
            End Property


            Public ReadOnly Property Date As DateNode
                Get
                    Return _current.Date
                End Get
            End Property


            Public Overrides Sub Add()

                If _list IsNot Nothing Then
                    ReDim Preserve _list(_list.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
                Else
                    ReDim _list(0)
                End If


                _current = New AlbumItem(_list.GetUpperBound(0))
                _list(_list.GetUpperBound(0)) = _current

            End Sub


            Public Function HasChildren() As Boolean

                Return False

            End Function

        End Class

        Public Class AlbumItem

            Private _attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
            Private _deleted As Boolean
            Private _index As Integer
            Private _text As String
            Private _Date As AlbumNode.DateNode



            Public Sub New(Index As Integer)

                _index = Index
                _Date = New AlbumNode.DateNode


            End Sub

            Public ReadOnly Property Attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
                Get
                    If _attributes Is Nothing Then
                        _attributes = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
                    End If
                    Return _attributes
                End Get
            End Property

            Public ReadOnly Property ListIndex As Integer
                Get
                    Return _index
                End Get
            End Property

            Public Property Text As String
                Get
                    Return _text
                End Get
                Set(value As String)
                    _text = value
                End Set
            End Property

            Public ReadOnly Property Date As AlbumNode.DateNode
                Get
                    Return _Date
                End Get
            End Property


        End Class



        Public Sub New()

            _current = New BandItem(0)

        End Sub


        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
            Get
                Return _current.Attributes
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property Current As BandItem
            Get
                Return _current
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property List As BandItem()
            Get
                Return _list
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides Property Text As String
            Get
                Return _current.Text
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _current.Text = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Public ReadOnly Property Album As AlbumNode
            Get
                Return _current.Album
            End Get
        End Property


        Public Overrides Sub Add()

            If _list IsNot Nothing Then
                ReDim Preserve _list(_list.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
            Else
                ReDim _list(0)
            End If


            _current = New BandItem(_list.GetUpperBound(0))
            _list(_list.GetUpperBound(0)) = _current

        End Sub


        Public Function HasChildren() As Boolean

            Dim Children As Boolean



            Return Children

        End Function

    End Class

    Public Class BandItem

        Private _attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Private _deleted As Boolean
        Private _index As Integer
        Private _text As String
        Private _Album As BandNode.AlbumNode



        Public Sub New(Index As Integer)

            _index = Index
            _Album = New BandNode.AlbumNode


        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property Attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
            Get
                If _attributes Is Nothing Then
                    _attributes = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
                End If
                Return _attributes
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property ListIndex As Integer
            Get
                Return _index
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Property Text As String
            Get
                Return _text
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _text = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property Album As BandNode.AlbumNode
            Get
                Return _Album
            End Get
        End Property


    End Class

    Private _FilePath As String


    Public Sub New()

        _current = New RecordsItem(0)
        _errors = New List(Of String)
        _orphans = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of XmlClassBase))

    End Sub


    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Get
            Return _current.Attributes
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Current As RecordsItem
        Get
            Return _current
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Errors As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return _errors
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property FilePath As String
        Get
            Return _FilePath
        End Get
        Set
            _FilePath = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property OrphanNodes As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of XmlClassBase))
        Get
            Return _orphans
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Property Text As String
        Get
            Return _current.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _current.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public ReadOnly Property Band As BandNode
        Get
            Return _current.Band
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function Load() As Boolean

        Dim Doc As xmldocument
        Dim Node As XmlNode = Nothing
        Dim r As Integer


        Doc = New XmlDocument()
        Doc.Load(_FilePath)

        For Each Node In Doc.ChildNodes
            If Node.Name <> "xml" Then 'Ignore any declarations.
                Exit For 'Only 1 root node allowed, any others are ignored.
            End If
        Next

        If Node.Attributes IsNot Nothing AndAlso Node.Attributes.Count > 0 Then
            For r = 0 To Node.Attributes.Count - 1
                Attributes.Add(Node.Attributes(r).Name, Node.Attributes(r).InnerText)
            Next
        End If

        LoadChildren(Node, String.Empty, Me)

        Return True

    End Function

    Public Function LoadChildren(xmlCurrent As XmlNode, ParentText As String, Parent As XmlClassBase) As XmlNode

        Dim xmlNodeText As XmlNode
        Dim Destination As XmlClassBase
        Dim r As Integer
        Dim strText As String


        For Each xmlChildNode As XmlNode In xmlCurrent.ChildNodes

            If xmlChildNode.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element Then

                Try
                    Destination = DirectCast(CallByName(Parent, xmlChildNode.Name, CallType.Get), XmlClassBase)
                Catch mme As MissingMemberException
                    _errors.Add(mme.Message)
                    Destination = New XmlClassBase
                    AddOrphan(xmlChildNode.Name, Destination)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    _errors.Add(ex.Message)
                    Throw
                End Try

                If Destination IsNot Nothing Then
                    If Destination.GetType.ToString <> "Records.XmlClassBase" Then
                        Destination.Add()
                    End If

                    strText = String.Empty

                    For Each xmlNodeText In xmlChildNode
                        If xmlNodeText.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text Then
                            strText &= xmlNodeText.InnerText.Trim
                        End If
                    Next

                    If strText <> String.Empty Then
                        Destination.Text = strText
                    End If

                    If xmlChildNode.Attributes IsNot Nothing AndAlso xmlChildNode.Attributes.Count > 0 Then
                        For r = 0 To xmlChildNode.Attributes.Count - 1
                            Destination.Attributes.Add(xmlChildNode.Attributes(r).Name, xmlChildNode.Attributes(r).InnerText)
                        Next
                    End If

                    If xmlChildNode.HasChildNodes Then
                        LoadChildren(xmlChildNode, xmlChildNode.Name, Destination)
                    End If

                End If

            End If

        Next

        Return xmlCurrent

    End Function

End Class

Public Class RecordsItem

    Private _attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Private _deleted As Boolean
    Private _index As Integer
    Private _text As String
    Private _Band As RecordsNode.BandNode



    Public Sub New(Index As Integer)

        _index = Index
        _Band = New RecordsNode.BandNode


    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Get
            If _attributes Is Nothing Then
                _attributes = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            End If
            Return _attributes
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ListIndex As Integer
        Get
            Return _index
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Text As String
        Get
            Return _text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Band As RecordsNode.BandNode
        Get
            Return _Band
        End Get
    End Property


End Class
```

The Load method works for as many xmlElements as the computer can handle.  I like it because it is nice and concise.  My issue is with the Save method.  I am not sure what is the best way.  I need to get all the classes under RecordsNode and write them out to xml.

I can use something like this Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetTypes() but hbow do I filter out all classes that are not children of RecordsNode?

The xml can be quite large.  I can just add code for each class instead of getting fancy.  That may be the safest and ugliest approach.

Or some other option?  This class may be used by customers so I can not guarantee anything about its destination working environment.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with C#, yet I see the `C#` tag there...

Comment: What you're trying to do here (save object data as text) is something known as serialization. .NET has an XmlSerializer class that can probably do a lot of the heavy lifting for you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Eric - I looked at that.  The problem with that is I START with XML.  That class starts with an object.  I have little faith that the serialized output will match the original XML.

Answer (score 0):

There is the XmlSerializer that do most of your work in an easier way. So create a class from your xml using `xsd.exe`, then fill that class with your data and after that Serialize the object like that:

```
 var o = new MyXmlObject();
 //add data to your object
 //...
 XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyXmlObject));

 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 using(XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
 {
     xs.Serialize(xw, o);
     using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("filepath"))
         sw.Write(sw.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: In fact, in Visual Studio 2015, you don't even need the XSD step.  Copy your XML, open any .cs file, and Paste Special -> XML to Classes.  It should generate your class files for you.  Works with JSON too.  Typically it's pretty decent.

Comment: I tried xsd.  The classes generated are terrible.  I end up with class names like BatchPatientDataRequisitionDataResultDataRequisitionErrorListRequisitionError.  Sorry but I can't give code like that to a customer.

Comment: Paste special uses the same libraries as xsd.  Creates unacceptable (for my standards anyway) classes.